# I need the file to be 1529 bytes and it does not work

Tags: java, file

Do I miss something? I need it to be 1529 bytes just. It's for my project and I can't understand what is going on.

I have a byte array, and I want to write one of them at a time randomly in the specified file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Cover {

public static byte[] aPenman = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102};
public static long mTabulable(String fileName) throws IOException {

    String path = "C:\\Users\\KOSTAS\\IdeaProjects\\prog\\src\\"+fileName;
    File file = new File(path);
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to open file " + fileName);
    }

    long sum = 0;
    try {
        int i = 0;
        while (file.length() != 1529){
            int rand = new Random().nextInt(aPenman.length);
            out.write(aPenman[rand]);
            if (i < 1347) {
                sum += aPenman[rand];
            }
            i++;
        }
        out.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Unable to open file " + fileName);
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you print the file's length each time through the loop, what does it look like? Can you guess what's happening? Does the name of the class you created an instance of for `out` give you a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are missing an:

```
out.flush();
```

just under your :

```
out.write(aPenman[rand]);
```

in the while loop

This forces any buffered output bytes to be written out to the underlying output stream.

Comment: Although this solves the problem, it would be better to track the number of bytes written instead of repeatedly checking `file.length()`, as right now the OP is writing and flushing individual bytes, which makes the use of a `BufferedOutputStream` useless.